# Data structure for grid with edge information

Tags: oop, data-structures, language-agnostic, grid

I want to implement a data structure of a grid of triangles shaped like this:

```
|---|---|---|  
| / | / | / |  
|---|---|---|  
| / | / | / |  
|---|---|---|
```

So every square cell is split in two triangle. The problem is that I need to store information for every edge of every cell. I thought about making a matrix of Object with every object containing 5 variables (4 edge + middle edge). But that means that there is redundancy because all edges are in common with some other cell.
Or I could make a matrix of edges, but that mean first row would have 3 columns, second 7, and so on.

IS there a better way? No specific programming language required, I can use OOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would use two structures:
- a sort of "net" of edges, where each edge holds its data and links to its neighboring edges.
- a map with some kind of triangle id as key and pointers to the triangle's 3 edges in the net as values.

Comment: actually, you could just make a set of edges and have each cell in the matrix hold pointers for it's edges. if you create an object representing a single edge instead of a single cell, you'll have no redundancy...